# CORS error when using HttpRequest.getString(url)

Tags: wordpress, dart, angular-dart, dart-html, wp-api

The whole application is built with `Angular 2` for `Dart`.

At one place I have a service with a really naive `HttpRequest.getString()` call with no special parameters or anything.

```
String response =  await HttpRequest.getString(url);
```

On the server side there is a `Wordpress` installation with `WP-API` running.

It seems, that `Dart` is creating **a new response header** for the currently loaded hostname somehow, because I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://my-wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/pages.
>
> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:8080, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

---

**I don't get the same result with `Postman`, though:**

> [image]

---

From what I could read out of the source code, [`Dart` itself concatenates duplicate headers into just one](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/dart/+/master/dart/tools/dom/templates/html/impl/impl_XMLHttpRequest.darttemplate#351), but I couldn't find any information on that extra CORS header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it by commenting out `Wordpress` specific `REST-API` code.
In the folder `wp-includes` there is a file called `rest-api.php`.

On line 376 upwards you see something like this:

```php
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . esc_url_raw( $origin ) );
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE' );
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
```

This seems to allow the host of the request to access the API. But since I'm already adding `*` as Origin, this will fail. So I just commented that code block out and everything works fine now.